# How to access the serialized data from inside web mothod using Ajax jquery form post using web methods c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Html**

```
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName"  runat="server"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName"  runat="server"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

<input type="file" Class="form-control" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" runat="server" />


  </div>
  <input type="button"   id="submit"  class="btn btn-default" runat="server"  value="Submit"/>




    </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").on("click", function (e) {


            //   alert($("form").serialize());
            var obj = '{"firstName":' +'"'+$("#firstName").val() + '"'+', "lastName":' + '"'+ $('#lastName').val() + '"}';
            console.log(obj);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", url: "WebForm1.aspx/CreateUser", data: obj /*$("form").serialize()*/
               ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log("Call Success");

                    alert(data.d);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    console.log("Call Fail");
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("Call Error");
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });

        });

        });
```

**Web Method**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static int CreateUser(String firstName, String lastName)
        {
            Users userObj = new Users();

            userObj.fileName = "xyz";// user.fileName;//fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
            userObj.firstName = firstName;//firstName.Value;
            userObj.lastName = lastName;//lastName.Value;
           // fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + "/Uploads/" + fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( Server.MapPath("~/") + "/Uploads/" + fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            SQLDAL sqldalobj = new SQLDAL();

            int success = sqldalobj.Create(userObj);

          //  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(user);
            return success;

        }
```

Right now I am able to pass text box values as json data and inside web method its received correctly.But when I need a larger number of text boxes using current approach its would result in large number of parameters which I want to avoid using a object as parameter instead of different parameters for each html form element.And using this approach I am failing upload the file .So my question is if I serialize the form and send the data to webmethod how to properly recieve the said serialized form and retrieve the data from it including the fileupload

Comment: you can simple debug and see what actually data you get from the other side. I think that you get each data separate by comma.

Comment: @Aristos for debugging the first part is then what should be the parameter of web method so as to receive the serialized form then only the part of debugging arises

Comment: place on web method a code like `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` or `Debug.Assert(false, "test");` and the debugger will start on that point.

Comment: Aristos still you dont understand my question  public static int CreateUser( ParameterType ParameterName) Is the defenition right so what will be the parameterType for serialized data then only the process of checking with debugger makes sense right ?

Comment: Yes you have right, I did not understand it. The serialize must be one long string, so one string only parameter - but you must try and see, I am not sure how you serialize your data...

Comment: @Aristos how I serialize my data is using $('form').serialize();