# Submit Button MVC 5 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC so please be gentle.

I have model -

```
public class LoanPayments
{
    public int PaymentNumber { get; set; }
    public string PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public double PaymentAmount { get; set; }
}

public class IndexModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Price")]
    public Double VehiclePrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Deposit Amount")]
    public Double DepositAmount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Date")]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Finance Option")]
    public string FinanceOption { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
    ....
```

I have a controller -

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        // Let's get all states that we need for a DropDownList
        var options = GetAllOptions();
        var tuple = new Tuple<IndexModel, DateTime>(new IndexModel(), new DateTime());
        // Create a list of SelectListItems so these can be rendered on the page
        tuple.Item1.Options = GetSelectListItems(options);
        return View(tuple);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitOptions(IndexModel stuff)
    {
        double vehicleAmount = stuff.VehiclePrice;
        double depositAmount = stuff.DepositAmount;
        DateTime deliveryDate = stuff.DeliveryDate;
        string financeOption = stuff.FinanceOption;
        int finOption = Convert.ToInt32(stuff.FinanceOption) * 12;
        return View("About");
    }
```

and view -

```
@using LoanRepaymentSystem.Models
@model Tuple<IndexModel, DateTime>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitOptions", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item1.VehiclePrice)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item1.VehiclePrice, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item1.DepositAmount)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item1.DepositAmount, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item1.DeliveryDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item1.DeliveryDate, String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Item2.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield, form-control", type = "date" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item1.Options)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item1.Options, Model.Item1.Options, "Please select a finance option ...", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Options" />
    </div>
 }
```

When I put values in all the fields and press the submit button the code

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SubmitOptions(IndexModel stuff)
```

in the controller runs.  However the IndexModel stuff values are not the ones that were entered, they are zeros and nulls.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Please help.

Kev

Comment: You cannot use a `Tuple` to generate form controls - look at the `name` attributes your generating - they have no relationship to your `IndexModel`. You need to pass just an instance if `IndexModel` to the view which will have `@model IndexModel`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor form asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557862/razor-form-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: And I have no idea what you think `Model.Item2.ToShortDateString()` in your `TextBoxFor()` is doing (it is adding a html attribute)

Comment: And your `DropDownListFor(m => m.Options, ..)` makes no sense either - you cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. Best guess is that your trying to bind the selected option to your `FinanceOption` property?)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that was help.